# Mantener sesión activa en ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, local-storage

Tengo una aplicación hecha con Ionic Framework y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para mantener la sesión activa.
Estuve intentando con `localStorage` pero no pude. Me darían una mano?
Este es mi controlador de la pantalla del login:

```
.controller('EntrarCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $http, $ionicPopup, $location, CONFIG, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    $rootScope.userToken = ''; 
        $scope.user={};
        $scope.user.username='';
        $scope.user.password =''; 

        $scope.doLogin = function() {
               $http.post('http://pixelesp.api.herokuapp.com/login',$scope.user).then(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp.data);

         $rootScope.userToken = resp.data.token;

         $scope.user = $rootScope.user;

         $scope.user = {};

          $http.get('http://pixelesp-api.herokuapp.com/me', {headers: {'auth-token': $rootScope.userToken}}).then(function(resp) {
            $rootScope.user = resp.data.data;
            console.log('token: '+$rootScope.userToken);

            console.log(resp.data.data);

            console.log('Succes', resp.data.data);

          }, function(err) {
            console.error('ERR', err);
            $location.path('/app/start');


            // err.status will contain the status code
          });

            $location.path('/app/inicio');



    }, function(err) {
      console.error('ERR', err);
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'Error en el ingreso',
             template: 'Usuario o contraseña invalido'
           });
           alertPopup.then(function(resp) {
             $location.path('/app/start');
           });
      // err.status will contain the status code
    });
    };
     $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)

})
```

Esto tenemos en nuestra api, realizada con Slim Framework:

```
app->post('/login', function () use ($app) {
$input = $app->request->getBody();

$username = $input['username'];
if(empty($username)){
    $app->render(500,array(
        'error' => TRUE,
        'msg'   => 'Se requiere nombre de usuario',
    ));
}


$password = $input['password'];
if(empty($password)){
    $app->render(500,array(
        'error' => TRUE,
        'msg'   => 'Se requiere contraseña',
    ));
}


$db = $app->db->getConnection();
$user =$db->table('usuarios')->select()->where('username', $username)->first();
if(empty($user)){
    $app->render(500,array(
        'error' => TRUE,
        'msg'   => 'El usuario no existe',
    ));
}

    if($user->password != $password){
    $app->render(500,array(
        'error' => TRUE,
        'msg'   => 'La contraseña no coincide',
    ));
}
$token = simple_encrypt($user->id, $app->enc_key);
$app->render(200,array('token' => $token));
});

$app->get('/me', function () use ($app) {   
$token = $app->request->headers->get('auth-token');
if(empty($token)){
    $app->render(500,array(
        'error' => TRUE,
        'msg'   => 'No has iniciado sesión 1',
    ));
}


$id_user_token = simple_decrypt($token, $app->enc_key);

$user = User::find($id_user_token);
if(empty($user)){
    $app->render(500,array(
        'error' => TRUE,
        'msg'   => 'No has iniciado sesión 2',
    ));
}
$app->render(200,array('data' => $user->toArray()));
});
```

Comment: Es correcto el uso del localStorage para conservar el token y poder enviarlo en los siguientes request que se realicen a la web api. Estas segura que definiendo el auth-token en el header alcanza ? Analiza el articulo http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api se que no usas webapi de asp.net mvc pero la idea es la misma. Junto al token se debe unit el "Bearer" quizas eso este faltando

Comment: Estas usando OAuth como mecanismo de autenticación?

Comment: Añadí el código de nuestra api, donde definimos el token @LeandroTuttini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que crees un servicio que te ayude a manejar los LocalStorage dentro de tu app. Por ejemplo :

```
.factory('sessionService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        set: function(key, value) {
            return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        },
        get: function(key) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        },
        destroy: function(key) {
            return localStorage.removeItem(key);
        },
    };
}])
```

Cuando tu usuario haga login por primera vez en tu app puedes hacer algo asi :

```
//Tu aqui debes agregar tu codigo que valida el login
if(loginExistoso){
    var token = "12345";
    sessionService.set("user_token", token);
}
```

Hacemos otro servicio para verificar que este valor exista, con las inyecciones de dependencia correspondientes.

```
 .factory('sessionStatus', ['$http', 'sessionService', '$location', function($http, sessionService, $location) {
    return {
        auth: function() {
            var token= sessionService.get("user_token");
            if ((token== "") || (token== null)) {
                $location.path('/login');
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
    };
}])
```

Y llamas desde donde quieras verificar esa informacion, inyectando este servicio.

```
if (sessionStatus.auth()) {
    $location.path('/app/home');
}
```